# Windows 11 - start menu not populated for a while after login

Tags: windows-11, start-menu

On all of my computers running Windows 11 (21H2, 22H2) with local accounts (no Microsoft account, no domain account).

I have been encountering the same problem since the moment I installed them: If I login to the system immediately after the reboot, start menu is not populated with my icons; it has very few of the default icons and that's it. I have just been running tests with one of my systems and it seems that if I delay logging in for 60 seconds, then the start menu will be fine.

If I login with less than a 30 seconds delay, the menu will be empty. If that happens, I can kill the Explorer process and start a new one, which will give me the usual start menu back. I wonder if anyone knows what could be possibly causing this strange behavior.

Comment: Something not correct. I have a couple of Windows 11 production machines.  Try running DISM.  Admin command prompt. dism.exe  /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth  followed by SFC/SCANNOW and restart.  Check for non-standard software and 3rd party start menu software.  I do not use the latter and start menu is very fast

Comment: Does it happen if you boot in Safe mode? Create also a new user account and see if it has this problem.

Comment: @John: No change. It works the same.

Comment: @harrymc: A new user account is not feasible for me. If it comes to that, it is better to reinstall completely and be more careful about the individual setup steps. I will try that but I can't do it now.

Comment: @harrymc: Safe mode doesn't seem to be making any difference.

Comment: I usually wait for the software to load everything, approx. 1 minute or less, before I even touch my mouse or press any buttons. Been using Windows since Windows 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

Given your responses, try a Windows 11 Repair Install.  3 methods.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.

Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.

Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

**(1) Keep Everything:** Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

If Keep Everything works, great, but may not work here.

**(2) Keep Data:** Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

If the problem is non-compliant software, this may work. Install software slowly to see.

**(3) Keep Nothing:** Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

If you Windows User Account is the issue, then number 3 is the only practical choice.

You can see if 1 or 2 work, or if you need to start again.

**Sort out:**   What software you install works and what does not.  Since you have multiple computers, this is important if you installed the same software on all of them.

Work on one system as a test.

I, too, have a couple of machines, and no issue, so I am confident that this is not a Windows issue.

Comment: I will probably do this as a last resort. I do have a precise list of changes to the OS so that I can easily replicate my work and stop the moment I notice something isn't working as intended. The problem is, it takes time (particularly in a case like this where a full reboot is needed). I am still hoping that perhaps somebody did encounter this specific problem and already knows what's causing it.

Comment: You have a troubleshooting approach and should follow it. You will likely find something interfering with the Start Menu or  closely related